# Whats happening with the timelike component in non-relativistic approx.?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, approximations

If we look at the non-relativistic approximation of an equation in Minkowski space, what happens to the timelike component in general? Like, my question is not the call for a specific Problem, but more what happens with the information kept inside the timelike component, it seems wrong to just don't pay attention to it anymore and keep calculate with the spatial components.

Comment: I think you may be conflating neglecting the timelike component, which we don't do, with recovering $3$-vector laws from $4$-vector laws in the $\beta\ll1$ limit.

Comment: for example the timelike component of 4-momentum is energy, which we definitely do pay attention to and calculate